# How do I stack a number Generator from Continuously Pressing the Same Button?

Tags: javascript

The button shown below produces 1(currency), but when I attempted to stack the button when pressing it twice, it produces an entirely different number and flickers between two. Below is the code :

```
function money() {
    clicks = document.getElementById("demo").nodeValue;
    setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = clicks = clicks + 1;
    }, 1000)
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, you can use the CSS property [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: I can't understand what are you trying to do, do you want to disable button once it is clicked?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Include the HTML in addition to the JavaScript. You can use the Stack Snippet functionality (button looks like `<>` in a page, in the editor).

Answer (score 0):

Concurrency... Put value reading very close to where you'll be using it

```
function money() {
    setInterval(function() {
        clicks = document.getElementById("demo").nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = clicks = clicks + 1;
    }, 1000)
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
}
```